# Convertir strings a floats en python

Tags: python

Hola necesito cambiar los elementos de esta lista para que sean convertidos a floats en PYTHON, existe alguna posibilidad?

```
 ['96,980', '144,000', '0', '149,520', '143,280', '58.957,738','160,02', '96,40', '0,20']
```

Trate con reemplazar las comas por puntos con **`replace`** pero el numero 58.957,738 quedaria -> 58.957.738, y no me sirve

Comment: Para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta recomiendo leas [ask], edites y agregues que llevas al momento

Comment: Pues el punto es para hacer la separación decimal osea quedaría de la siguiente forma ```58956.738```

Answer (score 1):

Usar `locale`:

```py
import locale

locale._override_localeconv["thousands_sep"] = "."
locale._override_localeconv["decimal_point"] = ","

num = ['96,980', '144,000', '0', '149,520', '143,280', '58.957,738','160,02', '96,40', '0,20']
res = [locale.atof(x) for x in num]
print(res) 
# [96.98, 144.0, 0.0, 149.52, 143.28, 58957.738, 160.02, 96.4, 0.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero tendrías que recorrer cada elemento

```
num = ['96,980', '144,000', '0', '149,520', '143,280', '58.957,738','160,02', '96,40', '0,20']
list_float=[]

for i in num:
     convert = float(i)
     list_float.append(convert)
print(list_float)
```

Con `float()` conviertes los números a flotantes

Comment: --ValueError: could not convert string to float: '96,980'--
No funciona

Comment: Creo que es por la coma, cámbialo por punto o has una función para sustituir la coma por puntlo

Comment: si sustituyo la coma por el punto el numero 58.957,738 quedaria como 58.957.738 y no es el numero que espero

Comment: Ya lo comenté en la pregunta

Comment: genial ya pude resolverlo, gracias!

Comment: De nada, podrías aceptar la respuesta

Comment: Tu código hace lo que se pide. También contiene errores sintácticos (`Print` no existe)

Comment: Lo siento es estoy con un celular

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO:

```
lista = ['96,980', '144,000', '0', '149,520', '143,280', '58.957,738','160,02', '96,40', '0,20']
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] = lista[i].replace(".", "")
    lista[i] = lista[i].replace(",", ".")
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] = float(lista[i])
print(lista)
```